# PDO sqlsrv: could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo

I trying to connect to an SQL Server in PHP. With XAMPP on my local machine, everything works well. But now I going to bring my application on the production server.

On this server there is installed the `Microsoft IIS 6.1` and running the PHP version `7.0.7`. I also installed the ODBC Driver from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/de-ch/download/details.aspx?id=36434). Next I decomment the following line in my php.ini file:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
```

I got the files from the [official microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

**What's my problem?**

Unfortunately, after I restarted the IIS. The PDO function throws the PDOException error with the following message:

```
could not find driver
```

For the connection I am using the following function which works pretty well on my local machine:

```
try {
    $con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=" . SERVER . ";Database=" . DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "No connection: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

What can I else do?

Comment: Do your server have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable ?

Comment: @Eimsas Yes. It has.

Comment: Then try to check logs, it should have more information than "could not find driver" I had same issue with WAMP, but then I just installed MS c++ and tried few versions of php_sqlsrv. Also restart is needed, at least in wamp.

Comment: For XAMPP on Windows yo will need the Thread Safe dll's not the NTS ( Not Thread Safe) version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After I found the error log on the Windows Server, I solved the error by myself.

I got this error in my log:

```
[21-Apr-2017 07:12:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '...\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
```

Then I downloaded again the [driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) and installed the x64-Driver. Finally It works without any problems.

Comment: wish to describe more how to install them? i just download and copy dll to extension folder in php folder named as php version after that restart iis but i cant see it in pdo list in     < ? php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: where did you see this error? On which log? How did you enable it?

Answer (score 14):

Here is detailed process if it's helpful for someone. `PHP Version - 7.4`

1. Download and extract the `.dll` files from this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
2. Paste the files in `C:\xampp\php\ext`, your path could be different.
3. in `php.ini` add those two lines at bottom or in extension section.

   ```
    extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll
    extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll
   ```
4. Restart your Xampp server, I'll suggest restart your computer and everything will work without an issue then.

**Check if SqlSRV enabled**

Check using `phpinfo()` or http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php at like this -

[image: SQLSrv Driver Check in PHP Info]

Hope, it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

please notice you must use the correct version of php_sqlsrv_xx_xts_xxx.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_xx_xts_xx.dll files.
[image]

for exmple if you use php version 7.4  and a 64 bit system and wamp you must download and use these files:
php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll
for download you can use [this site:](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2152937)
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2152937
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

It took some time for me to solve the 'No driver'-error. I went through some steps as mentioned here and found some other ones that helped me after new errors. For future references:

- Download the latest drivers from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) (as said by Julian Schmuckli).
- Check if your XAMPP is 64 bits(!) with [Phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). If you've got 32-bit, you need different drivers.
- Add the drivers to your Php.ini file and save the dll's in your php/ext-folder (question of saber tabatabaee yazdi).
- For the connection, use this code:

```cs
$dbh = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$dbname",$username,$pw);
```

**If you add a port, use:**

```cs
$server = "192.168.1.15, 51022";
```

Where the IP (can be hostname to) is your server and 51022 your port.