# Could not connect with Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword. could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a SQL Server running the OS Windows Server 2012 R2. It is running Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

On another computer, I am running an IIS web server, and I have installed PHP version 7.2.13, and Microsoft Driver 5.3 for PHP for SQL Server.

I am trying to connect to a database on the SQL Server via PHP:

```
<?php

// Now connect to an Azure SQL database by setting Authentication to ActiveDirectoryPassword
$azureServer = "vgissql";
$azureDatabase = "dbo.pctProjectTracking";
$azureUsername = "myuid";
$azurePassword = "mypassword";
$connectionInfo = "Database = $azureDatabase; Authentication = ActiveDirectoryPassword;";

try
{
    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server = $azureServer ; $connectionInfo", $azureUsername, $azurePassword );
    echo "Connected successfully with Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword.\n";
    $conn = null;
}
catch( PDOException $e )
{
    echo "Could not connect with Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword.\n";
    print_r( $e->getMessage() );
    echo "\n";
}

?>
```

If I try opening this php file in a browser, I get:

Could not connect with Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword. could not find driver

Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490144/pdo-sqlsrv-could-not-find-driver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO sqlsrv: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490144/pdo-sqlsrv-could-not-find-driver)