# Installing on XAMPP PHP7.4.11 SQLSRV drivers

Tags: php, dll, xampp

So technically this should be a straightforward setup.
Downloaded .dll files from https://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv/5.9.0preview1/windows

- php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
- php_sqlsrv.dll

Placed them in C:\xampp\php\ext

Opened php.ini

Referenced them as extension right where the other pdo's are set:

extension=pdo_sqlsrv
extension=sqlsrv

Saved the file, started XAMPP, echo out phpinfo(), and I don't see no "sqlsrv" anywhere.

Also, my code shows "Error!: could not find driver;"

Been reading a whole bunch of stuff but nothing that gives me anything new to try.

Now everything I find online is either old PHP 5.+ or PHP 7.0 I am using 7.4 not sure if that is the problem.

Need some Help.

Comment: Did you download MS drivers per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64337728/1255289? See also installation instructions here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql "Note that the precompiled binaries have different names -- substitute accordingly in php.ini"

Comment: Thank you so much. I had downloaded from the same site, but I did not get anything higher than ts_72. That was it, as soon as I added the new, ts_74 .dll and referenced them in php.ini it showed up. I appreciated the help.